# ElasticSearch filter on array along with multiple match queries

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I am trying to filter the documents based on some tags and subcategory.

**Some documents:**

```
[{
    "_id" : "2oukjh8o9qy2ejhasdkqwe",
    "productName" : "ASSORTED DOUGHNUT 1PC",
    "productSubCategory" : [
        {
            "label" : "Veg",
            "imageUrl" : "/catImg/fandA.svg"
        }
    ],
    "isVisible" : true,
    "tags" : [
        {
            "tagImageUrl" : " ",
            "label" : "Favorites",
            "tag" : "favorites"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : "638daf9f42e6efc7f06641c2",
    "isVisible" : true,
    "productName" : "FILTER COFFEE",
    "productSubCategory" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("638daf18ed445826c06a7328"),
            "label" : "Veg"
        }
    ],
    "tags" : [
        {
            "tagImageUrl" : " ",
            "label" : "Trending",
            "tag" : "trending"
        },
        {
            "tagImageUrl" : " ",
            "label" : "Favorites",
            "tag" : "favorites"
        },
        {
            "tagImageUrl" : " ",
            "label" : "Cabin Friendly",
            "tag" : "cabinfriendly"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : "6389d7f942e6efc7f05d51e0",
    "isVisible" : true,
    "productName" : "ILLY DOPPIO",
    "productSubCategory" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("638d97236612ca5d5ceb53b9"),
            "label" : "Non-Veg"
        }
    ],
    "tags" : [
        {
            "tagImageUrl" : " ",
            "label" : "Cabin Friendly",
            "tag" : "cabinfriendly"
        }
    ]
}]
```

**Query I am trying**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "productSubCategory.label": {
                            "query": "Veg",
                            "operator": "and"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "isVisible": true
                    }
                }
            ],
            "filter": {
                "terms": {
                    "tags.tag": [
                        "favorites",
                        "cabinfriendly"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Requirement**

The result documents must have any of the tags.tag provided in the query. Must have isVisible as true and productSubCategory.label as provided in the query.

With the above query I am getting Non-Veg items as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `match query` which will do the free text search and it will match with the non-veg as well. You can use `term query` with `keyword` type insted of match query like shown below:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "productSubCategory.label.keyword": {
              "value": "Veg"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "isVisible": true
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "tags.tag": [
            "favorites",
            "cabinfriendly"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please note that i have replace field name `productSubCategory.label`  with `productSubCategory.label.keyword`